# How do I get to this formula for the area of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am new here and new student to geometry.
In my geometry skript there is a task:

Show that the formula for the area $F$ of a triangle with sidelengths $a,b,c $ is given by
$$F^2 = - \frac{1}{16} \det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & c^2 & b^2 & 1 \\ c^2 & 0 & a^2 & 1 \\ b^2 & a^2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1& 1& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
This drives me crazy because I cant see how to get there.

I do know how to get to
$F= \frac12 \det \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3 & y_3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $
and $ F = \frac12 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ a & b & c \end{pmatrix} $

I also thought about using Heron's formula for the square of a triangle:

$ F^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) $ where $s= \frac{a+b+c}{2} $

I did multiplied it all out and can't seem to find a pattern..
Hope this question is appropriate.

Maybe here is someone who has an idea :)

Comment: See the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant).

Comment: Surely Heron is the way for this. But I guess there's a more elegant way

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I dont think I can use it as a tool yet

Comment: @Exodd Oh thats a little promising..than I have to try to figure it out from there further..

Comment: @user1051982 That's interesting, because I can't think of a geometric interpretation of squaring the determinant. Now, of course the squared area goes well with Heron's formula, so maybe you can start from there.

Comment: If you multiplied it all out, can you edit the question to include the resulting polynomial?

Comment: I am confused by your posting.  If I had such a problem, I would immediately forgo elegance, and multiply everything out.  Then, I would compare the results with Heron's formula.  If it matches, you are done.  If not, then I would include in my posting all of the work that I have done, including multiplying out the determinant, and demonstrating why I think that the result is inconsistent with Heron's formula.  Personally, I do not understand why you would present such a posting without first doing everything that I have suggested.

Comment: Your last equality for $F$ in the line that starts "I do know how to get" is surely incorrect: that is a $2\times 3$ matrix, so it does not have a determinant. You are missing a row.

Comment: Both sides are fully symmetric quadratics in $a^2,\,b^2,\,c^2$ equal to $3a^4$ for equaliteral triangles. Unfortunately, that doesn't have a unique solution, but you can probably fix that with another special case involving right-angled triangles.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the determinant of a rectangular matrix is also defined (see Radić M.: A Definition of Determinant of Rectangular Matrix for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c^2 & b^2 & 1 \\ c^2 & 0 & a^2 & 1 \\ b^2 & a^2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1& 1& 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}

Perform the column transformations $C_2 \to C_2 - C_1$ and $C_3 \to C_3- C_1$ which don't change the determinant.
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c^2 & b^2 & 1 \\ c^2 & -c^2 & a^2-c^2 & 1 \\ b^2 & a^2-b^2 & -b^2 & 1 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}

Perform the row transformations $R_2 \to R_2 - R_1$ and $R_3 \to R_3 - R_1$ which also leave the determinant unchanged.
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c^2 & b^2 & 1 \\ c^2 & -2c^2 & a^2-c^2-b^2 & 0 \\ b^2 & a^2-b^2-c^2 & -2b^2 & 0 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}

A simple Laplace expansion, first along the fourth row then along the third column of the resulting submatrix, will tell you that the determinant of this matrix is in fact the determinant of the central matrix
\begin{pmatrix} -2c^2 & a^2-c^2-b^2\\ a^2-b^2-c^2 & -2b^2 \end{pmatrix}

which is just equal to $$
4b^2c^2 - (a^2-b^2-c^2)^2 = (2bc)^2 - (a^2-b^2-c^2)^2\\=(a^2-b^2+2bc-c^2)(a^2-b^2-2bc-c^2) \\= (a^2 - (b+c)^2) (a^2-(b-c)^2) \\
= (a-b-c)(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)
$$

Recognizing the semi-perimeter $2S = a+b+c$, we just have $$
a-b-c = 2(a-S) \\
a+b+c = 2S \\
(a+b-c) = 2(S-c)\\
(a+c-b) = 2(S-b)
$$
which leads to $$
(a-b-c)(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b) = 16S(S-c)(S-b)(a-S) = -16F^2
$$
where $F$ is the area of the triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and $F^2 = S(S-a)(S-b)(S-c)$ by Heron's formula. That is, the determinant at the start equals $-16F^2$, as desired.